# pointer in post increment ++ operator overloading

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

```
Clock Clock::operator++(int x)
{
    Clock oldState= *this;
    tick();

    return *oldState;
}
```

The operator overloading function creates an object oldState which points to *this. What does that mean? Is it assigning the address of the local object to oldState? Or is it using the = operator overloading (which calls the copy constructor). What does it do?

and to return *oldState, wouldn't it be out of scope since you're not declaring it on the heap?

Comment: `oldState` is not a pointer so it cannot point to anything. It's a copy of `*this`. What `*oldState` means is anyone's guess. Perhaps there's unary `operator*` overloaded for `Clock`.

Answer (score 4):

First of all this code

```
Clock Clock::operator++(int x)
{
    Clock oldState= *this;
    tick();

    return *oldState;
}
```

is invalid because the returned expression can not be converted to type Clock. The return expression has type Clock * not Clock. The correct operator could look the following way

```
Clock Clock::operator++( int )
{
    Clock oldState= *this;
    tick();

    return oldState;
}
```

This statement

```
    Clock oldState= *this;
```

means that new object with name oldState is created by using copy constructor applied to the original object (that is to *this). And this object is returned by the function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Will it be out of scope if you return the oldState since you're declaring it within the function?

Comment: Not if you return it by value - if you return it by reference or as a pointer, you'll have problems, but when you return by value a copy gets made for the caller =)

Comment: `*oldState` is (probably) not type `Clock*`.  If it compiles at all, it's equivalent to `oldState.operator*()`, which *might* have a type convertible to `Clock`, but that would be really weird.  It's probably just a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

`return *oldState;` appears to be a bug and should be `return oldState;`

`return oldState;` is okay since it returns a copy on the stack

`Clock oldState= *this;` does indead make a copy and store it in oldState

Answer (score 0):

`*this` is the current instance of `Clock`. As you rightly say, this calls the copy constructor but this method should `oldState`.

Answer (score 0):

It is copy the current state to a fresh new object `Clock` that is allocated on the stack, then really do the increment and then return the previously saved object (except that I do think there is a typo and there should be no `*` before the `oldState` otherwise it won't compile).

This is the the expected behaviour as postfix increment are supposed to return the state of the object prior to the increment. On int, it does not shock you ?

```
unsigned int i = 2;
std::cout << i++ << std::endl;
```

Output will be `2`, whereas for:

```
unsigned int i = 2;
std::cout << ++i << std::endl;
```

Output will be `3`.

Same thing is supposed to happen for all the object that do support postfix increment.